# Cardinals without Axiom of choice?

Tags: set-theory, cardinal-arithmetic

When comparing the size of sets using 1-1 functions ($ x\approx y$), AC is used to ensure the existence of a unique ordinal $|x|$ which is a $\approx$-representative of each class [$x$].

This in turn allows to use transfinite induction on ordinals to prove facts about cardinals, for example that for each infinite cardinal $\kappa$, $|\kappa\times\kappa| = |\kappa|$. (*)

Is it consistent with ZF without AC that there exists an infinite cardinal $\kappa$ such that $[\kappa\times\kappa] > [\kappa]$?

If so, could you please give me some references for the construction of such a model ?

If not, do you know a proof of (*) that doesn't rely on AC ?

Answer (score 14):

Tarski showed that under ZF, AC is equivalent with the assertion that $\mathfrak{m}^2=\mathfrak{m}$ for all infinite cardinals $\mathfrak{m}$.
See Tarski "Sur quelques theorems qui equivalent a l'axiome du choix", or see the following wikipedia article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarski%27s_theorem_about_choice

(But  note that for the $\aleph_\alpha$'s, i.e. for wellordered cardinals, ZF proves that $(\aleph_\alpha)^2=\aleph_\alpha$.)

Comment: Thank you. My question was not clear since I used the notation |x| under the assumption ZF-AC, which doesn't make sense for any set x in that context. I edited accordingly. Do you know a construction of a model of ZF-AC with an explicit such infinite cardinal ?

Comment: Any infinite Dedekind-finite set $X$ satisfies $\mathrm{card}(X^2)\neq\mathrm{card}(X)$: just note that from an injection $\pi:X^2\to X$ yields an injection from $X$ to a proper subset, by fixing some $a\in X$, and mapping $x\mapsto\pi(a,x)$.

Comment: Yes sure,but we are turning around : is there an explicit construction of an infinite Dedekind-finite set in some model of ZF - AC ?

Comment: @huurd It depends on what you mean by "explicit", of course. But of course we can find models of ZF (aside: ZF - AC makes no sense, since AC is not an axiom of ZF) with infinite Dedekind-finite sets. This is how we prove their existence is consistent with ZF. See Noah's answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3063341/7062).